# A day at the Horse Races

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

### Background

Back in the late 90's / first 00's when Flash Web Design was so much cool that noone could live without having a full Flash website, or at least an animated widget, I was hired to develop a "horse races viewer" in Flash/Actionscript, in the shape of an 80's videogame style animation, so the site's visitors could not only read the race results, but they could see it in a moving animation! *WOW! Impressive!*

They provided me a CSV file with all the races details: start and arrival order, horse names, driver names, prizes, etc. My Flash app read that file for each race and displayed the above said animation.

Nowadays the Flash support is significantly declined, so we must revert to **ascii-art**!

### Task

Your task is to create a full program or function that reads the race data in CSV format from standard input and outputs an ascii-art representation of the race as shown in the example below.

**INPUT**

CSV data with 2 fields: 1) start order; 2) arrival time at the Finish in the format `1.13.4` (1 minute, 13 seconds, 4 tenths of second). If the time reports `R` means that the horse is Retreated (didn't finish the race) due to incident, fall or other reason. Note: The arrival time could be the same for 2 or more horses, in this case they share the arrival position.

```
1,1.13.4
2,1.13.0
3,R
4,1.12.7
5,1.11.5
6,1.13.4
7,1.12.1
8,1.17.9
```

**OUTPUT**

For each CSV row, output a racetrack like this:

```
1_|______________4(1.13.0)___________________________
```

The racetrack is composed by:

- `1` which is the horses start order.
- `_|` where `_` is a spacer and the `|` is the finish line.
- 50 x `_` that represents 50 tenths of second.
- `5(1.13.4)` that is the arrival position followed by the arrival time. This must be positioned respecting the time differences between horses. For example: you position the 1st arrived on the Finish line at time `1.11.5`, the second arrives at time `1.12.1`, the difference is `1.12.1 - 1.11.5 = 6` tenths of second, so the second horse should be positioned at the 6th character, and so on. If the time difference is more than 50 tenths of seconds (or 5 seconds) you must position the horse at the end. The same if the horse is `R` (Retreated).

So the whole racetrack for the CSV data above should be:

```
  F=Finish line
1_|____________________________5(1.13.4)_____________
2_|______________4(1.13.0)___________________________
3_|__________________________________________________R
4_|___________3(1.12.7)______________________________
5_1(1.11.5)__________________________________________
6_|____________________________5(1.13.4)_____________
7_|_____2(1.12.1)____________________________________
8_|__________________________________________________6(1.17.9)
  012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

There is no need to add `F=Finish line`, and the last line `0123456789...` that is only for explaining purpose.

### Test cases

```
RACE:
1,1.14.9
2,R
3,R
4,1.14.2
5,1.15.2
6,1.15.3
7,1.15.3

RACE:
1,1.13.6
2,1.13.8
3,R,
4,1.15.9
5,1.13.8
6,R,
7,1.14.4
8,1.15.6
9,1.14.1
10,1.13.9
11,1.13.2
12,1.14.3
13,1.15.0

RACE:
1,1.13.4
2,1.13.0
3,R
4,1.12.7
5,1.11.5
6,1.13.4
7,1.12.1
8,1.17.9

RACE:
1,1.17.3
2,1.20.4
3,1.17.0
4,1.18.8
5,1.18.5
6,1.18.4
7,1.18.4
8,1.17.8
9,1.18.3
10,1.18.7
11,R

RACE:
1,1.17.5
2,R
3,1.17.7
4,1.16.9
5,1.16.1
6,1.18.9

RACE:
1,1.12.8
2,1.13.0
3,1.13.2
4,1.12.7
5,1.11.5
6,1.13.0
7,1.12.1
8,1.12.8
```

### Rules

- Shortest code wins.

Comment: In the example where 5th is tied, wouldn't horse 8 still place 7th?

Comment: May we assume that the minute number will always be `1`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan It depends on the rules, in the example I assumed that if the horses share the 5th position, the next will be considered 6th.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes you can assume the minute is always 1.

Comment: What range will the second be in?

Comment: Also, may we assume that there will always be a non-`R` horse? (I know this isn't a sensible question in real life, but this is code.)

Comment: @Pietu1998 You can assume that there will always be a non-R horse. Regarding "What range will the second be in?" I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean, will there be times such as `1.02.3` or `1.59.3`, or is there a limit to the seconds place too?

Comment: @Pietu1998 OK, you can assume that all the times will be more than 1 and under 2 minutes, referring to this type of race.

Comment: How is the start order formatted when there are more than 9 horses?

Comment: @Arnauld you should keep the finish line | vertically aligned, so you can add a space or 0 before the numbers < 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 261 bytes

Takes an array of time strings `"1.ss.t"` as input. The start order is implicit.

```js
a=>a.map((t,i)=>(u='_',++i>9?'':' ')+i+u+u.repeat(x=(x=t>'9'?50:t.slice(2)*10-s[0].slice(2)*10)>50?50:x,p=s.indexOf(t)+1+`(${t})`).replace(u,'|')+(x<50?p:'')+u.repeat((x=50-p.length-x)>0?x:0)+(x>0?'':t>'9'?t:p),s=a.filter((v,i)=>a.indexOf(v)==i).sort()).join`
`
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>a.map((t,i)=>(u='_',++i>9?'':' ')+i+u+u.repeat(x=(x=t>'9'?50:t.slice(2)*10-s[0].slice(2)*10)>50?50:x,p=s.indexOf(t)+1+`(${t})`).replace(u,'|')+(x<50?p:'')+u.repeat((x=50-p.length-x)>0?x:0)+(x>0?'':t>'9'?t:p),s=a.filter((v,i)=>a.indexOf(v)==i).sort()).join`
`

console.log(f([
  "1.13.4",
  "1.13.0",
  "R",
  "1.12.7",
  "1.11.5",
  "1.13.4",
  "1.12.1",
  "1.17.9"
]));

console.log(f([
  "1.13.6",
  "1.13.8",
  "R",
  "1.15.9",
  "1.13.8",
  "R",
  "1.14.4",
  "1.15.6",
  "1.14.1",
  "1.13.9",
  "1.13.2",
  "1.14.3",
  "1.15.0"
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>282</s> <s>272</s> 246 bytes

Similar to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98457/53667) the input is assumed to be already stripped from the starting number since it is implicit.

```python
H=input().split("\n")
T=[float(c[2:])if c[2:]else 99for c in H]
P=[min(int(10*(t-min(T))),50)for t in T]
S=sorted(list(set(T)))
i=0
u="_"
for h,p,t in zip(H,P,T):i+=1;s=S.index(t)+1;print`i`+u+"|"*(s>1)+u*p+[h,"%d(%s)"%(s,h)][t<99]+u*(41-p+(s<2))
```